# Include AdditiveGaussianNoise to customized ImageDataGenerator(sequence)

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation, data-generation

I constructed the following `DataGenerator` for image data.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

`x_set` are my input data (images; the file paths to this images) and `y_set` the output data (labels). I now want to add ImageAugmentation and I would like to use `AdditiveGaussianNoise` (https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/overview/arithmetic.html#additivegaussiannoise) to add Gaussian Noise to the input data.

```
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa
aug = iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(scale=(0, 0.2*255))
```

How can I include this to my `DataGenerator` and extend the Generator by `ImageAugmentation`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So batch_x is a np.array containing images? Maybe I am misunderstanding something but it seems like it is almost the same as in the [documentation](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_basics.html#a-standard-use-case):

**Edited**

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])

        # cast to integer for imgaug
        batch_x = batch_x.astype(np.uint)

        # apply augmentation
        aug = iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(scale=(0, 0.2*255))
        batch_x = aug(images=batch_x)

        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255

        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got this error: `ValueError: Got dtype 'float64' in augmenter 'UnnamedAdditiveGaussianNoise' (class 'AddElementwise'), which is a forbidden dtype (uint32, uint64, uint128, uint256, int32, int64, int128, int256, float64, float96, float128, float256).` when trying to use model.fit_generator.

Comment: Ah I think you have to do the augmentation before you normalize with /255. Try to move the normalization part after the augmenation.

Comment: These are images right? So the values should be intergers. But when you print out batch_x.shape you get float64? If so, cast it to uint8: 
```batch_X = batch_x.astype(np.uint8)```

Comment: That works, thanks! Maybe you would like to amend your answer? :-) One additional stupid question: is it a problem that I had batch_x.shape = float64 or is this okay as well? Or do I have to change the variable type to uint8 in general?

Comment: No its not a problem. It's just the libary imgaug that wants it as an integer. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You will receive the bounty as soon as possible ;-)

Comment: One more thing! Can you check if batch_x has now still the same length as batch_y?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get this completely. I use: `training_generator = DataGenerator_aug(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16)
validation_generator = DataGenerator_aug(X_val, y_val, batch_size=16)` to apply the `DataGenerator` to the data. And X_train and y_train have length of 10.000 and X_val and y_val 2.000. What else should I check? batch_size is 16 as stated in the code above.

Comment: I thought for some reason that imgaug multiplies the input images (ie one image in -> 5 augmentated images out). But thats not the case. But I think you should add a probability to the augmentator:
```aug = iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(0.5, scale=(0, 0.2*255))``` (note the "0.5")
So that every image has the probabiliy of 50% to get noise.